# Using media queries in calculations with scss

Tags: css, media-queries, sass

I want to have a calclation that is based on the width and height of the window

I know I can use `@media min-width: 700px` to have css work only when width is 700px at minimum.

is there a way to have something like this?:

```
$calc = percentage((@media.width)/200)*3);

div{
width: $calc
}
```

in which I use the width or height of the window in my calculation the same way that the css checks for the current width and compares it with the min-width

Comment: Just like CSS, Sass does not know the width/height of the browser.  CSS just gives instructions to the browser on how to render something.

Comment: Yea, SASS is just a preprocessor. SASS will never even see a browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look at jquery ..

- http://api.jquery.com/width/
- http://api.jquery.com/height/

In the mean while, can you elaborate your question. What is the context of the code you want to write ? PHP, css, html, javascript ??

Also, take a look at the CSS function Calc()

- http://caniuse.com/calc

Carry on.